# How to get the only phone number from the device contact, not whats app and duo number, etc

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-cursor

How to get the only phone number from the device contact, not whats app and duo number, etc...

Example:
I got the device contact number, but that return

1. Phone Number
2. What's App Number
3. Google Duo Number etc...

Note: I need only a phone number from the local device contact.

```
val phones: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
        null,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
        arrayOf(contactId),
        null
    )

// This will return list of contact number
val phoneNumbers: Int = it.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)
```

Answer (score 1):

Reference:- https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-details

The above Link has - ContactsContract.Data.DATA1
that only retrieves the phone number
checkout above link for more detail

Comment: I tried the reference link but didn't get it. Can you add a sample code here?

Answer (score 0):

try this one i hope this will help you.

```
//ContactsContract defines an extensible database of contact-related information
    var uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI

    val PROJECTION = arrayOf(
        ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID,
        ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.Data.PHOTO_URI,
        ContactsContract.Data.DATA1
    )


    var cursor =
        contentResolver.query(uri, PROJECTION, ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?", arrayOf(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
        ), ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC ", null)

    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        val contactId =
            cursor!!.getString(cursor!!.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID))
        val photo = cursor!!.getString(cursor!!.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.PHOTO_URI))
        val name = cursor!!.getString(cursor!!.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME))
        val phone = cursor!!.getString(cursor!!.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1))
    }
```

Comment: I tried above the code, and it didn't work